# Resetting a number in a number count (Python)

Tags: python, count, numbers, reset

If I have say a number like 11, but I want it to go into a number count of 0-6
How would I do it?

I know the answer would be 4 on the number count as it would count 7 times from 0 to 6 then reset and count 4 more times to total the number 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the *remainder*; use the `%` operator:

```
>>> 11 % 7
4
```

Comment: Nice one, I triggered the "minimum answer length threshold" when answering this question.

Comment: is it called _remainder_ or _risidue_ in english?

Comment: Oh my, facepalm. Why didn't I think of this?!
Thanks!

Comment: @alko: The remainder.